# Joomla php echo meta robots tag in template?

Tags: php, templates, joomla, meta

I wonder if it's possible to php echo the robots meta tag in a template in Joomla.

For example, if I do something like this:

```
$doc =JFactory::getDocument(); 
$meta_description = $doc->getMetaData("description");
```

I can echo the meta description via

```
<?php echo "$meta_description"; ?>
```

Is this also somehow possible with the robots tag?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robots configuration is part of the main Joomla! configuration hence you can retrieve it with:

```
$jconfig = JFactory::getConfig();
$robots = $jconfig->get('robots', '');
```

The default (installation) value is an empty string, otherwise you can expect it to have a combination of the values: `index,follow,noindex,nofollow`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works fine.